# Pinging the server periodically with jQuery and Rails without a form, updating a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, rest

I'm sort of a noob, so please bear with me!

I'm trying to--when a user is signed in on the dashboard--have jQuery periodically ping the server every X seconds and update the user's 'heartbeat' with the current datetime and set 'online' to true.

I'm probably missing some RESTful concepts and concepts involving communication between jQuery and Rails. Just finished Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial and am building off his sample app.

I've done research, but answers mostly involve filling out a form; I want to do this without one.

So I need to somehow pass into jQuery a :user_id and link it to the correct URI. I have a states controller and a states model that belongs_to a user (who has_one of them). Heartbeat and Online are in the states table.

rake routes shows that: PUT    /states/:id(.:format)          states#update

**states_controller.rb**

```
class StatesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:thump]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:thump]

  def new
  end
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    user.update_attributes(heartbeat: Time.now, online: true)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

**application.js**

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({ 
  'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")}
})

// Periodically updates heartbeat
$(function(){
    setInterval (thump, 3000);
    var js = '<thump> ';
    function thump(){
        console.log(js + 'Test');       
        $.ajax({
            url: 'states/update',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(js + result);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the user that you're trying to perform on is the same as the currently signed  on user, it seems like you should 't need to pass anything, just use current_user (or whatever) in your controller, instead of passing an id and re-fetching the same object again.

Comment: This is true... trying this now.

Comment: Right on, I'm a big fan of the KISS principle... Good luck.

Comment: Also, using current_user makes it more tamper-proof. I'm not sure if it matters in this specific application, but it is something to keep in mind for similar problems in the future.

Comment: POST http://localhost:3000/states/thump 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js:8241
send jquery.js:8241
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:7720
thump

Thanks, definitely good to know. But yes, I have no idea why I'm getting an internal server error now... any idea? Otherwise I'll be spending some time toying with the rails console. x_x

Comment: Still getting 500 (Internal Server Error). And that's the same with both methods implemented. It looks like I've got another problem in my states controller, specifically my thump method... Sigh, I shall sleep on this one...

Answer (score 0):

Why not change your .js file to look like this:

```
function giveLife(url) {
    setInterval (thump, 3000);
    var js = '<thump> ';
    function thump(){
        console.log(js + 'Test');       
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(js + result);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and put this in the view that you want to start the heartbeat on:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
         giveLife(<%= states_path(@state, @user_id).to_json %>);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
         giveLife( &quot;/states&quot; );
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &
    });
</script>

Throwing a weird error. But I really like this method... I read somewhere js has some issues escaping rails vars. Is that what's going on here?

Comment: `raw states_path(@state, @user_id).to_json`